# Uniqueness of fractions with prime denominators

Tags: prime-numbers, fractions

I was thinking about fractions with prime denominators and wanted to confirm something. If I have two fractions less than 1  with different prime denominators, is it certain that these two fractions can never be equal. I will try to state it more formally:

Given two fractions with prime denominators

$\frac{a}{p_1}$ and $\frac{b}{p_2}$

Where $a,b \in \Bbb Z$ ; $a<p_1$ ; $b < p_2$ ; $p_1 \not = p_2$

Show that there are no $a$ and $b$ for which $\frac{a}{p_1} = \frac{b}{p_2}$

Comment: For the fractions to be equal $ap_2=bp_1$. The only way this can happen with positive integer $a,b$ is if $a=p_1,\;b=p_2$, but that would mean that the fractions are equal to $1$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks, thats along the lines of what I was thinking but my confidence with math proofs is low so I wanted to verify :)

Comment: @AleksandrAlbert Note that based on what you wrote, since $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$, note $a = kp_1$ and $b = kp_2$, for any integer $k \le 0$, meet all of the conditions. However, I assume this is not what you want.

Comment: @DonThousand it actually implies the distinct parts of a and b are those, a and b can have any gcd they want though.

Comment: @Roddy Not with $a<p_1,\;b<p_2$

Answer (score 1):

$\frac a{p_1} = \frac b{p_2} \iff$

$ap_2 = bp_1$.

This means $p_2|bp_1$ and as $p_2$ is prime $p_2|b$ or $p_2|p_1$ (Euclid's Lemma).  But $p_1$ is a prime not equal to $p_2$ so $p_2|p_1$ is impossible so $p_2|b$.

But this means $\frac b{p_2}$ is an integer.

If we let $k:=\frac b{p_2}$ this would mean $a = p_1*k$ and $b=p_2*k$ and $\frac a{p_1} = \frac b{p_2} = k$.  That's simple enough...

...but you said $b < p_2$ (and $a<p_1$ and that's impossible of $p_2|b$.  So we have a contradiction.

=====

As a side note you should be aware that every rational number when written as a fraction $\frac ab$ so that $b\in \mathbb N$ and $a \in \mathbb Z$ will have only *one* unique expression in lowest terms.

So if $\frac a{p_1} = \frac b{p_2}$ but $p_1 \ne p_2$ and $a \ne b$ then it is *not* possible that these are both in lowest terms.

But if $\frac a{p_1}$ is not in lowest terms then there must be $k > 1$ so that $a= N*k$ and $p_1 = q*k$.  But $p_1$ is prime so that would mean $k=p_1$ and $q=1$ so $\frac a{p_1} = N$. And $a=Np_1$.  That would mean $\frac b{p_2}=N$ so $b=N{p_2}$ and we $a = Np_1$ and $b=Np_2$.

We'd have gotten the exact same results if we tried figuring $\frac b{p_2}$ wasn't in lowest terms first.

As you said $\frac a{b_2} = \frac b{p_2} < 1$ we know this case the above is impossible.